# When are Galaxy At War N7 Operation Bonuses awarded?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I would like to know when do you get the commendation pack for completing an N7 Operations weekend -- immediately, or after the operation ends?

Also are the bonuses cumulative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, the Victory and Commendation packs have always been awarded in the week *following* the N7 operation, usually on Tuesday or Wednesday of next week.

N7 weapons earned from Commendation packs are just like any other weapon in multiplayer - they start at level 1, and must be earned again to advance to the cap of level 10. So yes, the awards are cumulative - if you earn an N7 Hurricane I in one operation, you can then earn an N7 Hurricane II in the next, *or* you could earn an N7 Eagle I instead. It's just the luck of the draw.